# How to make a toolbaritem appear by default for a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm adding a toolbaritem with a child toolbarbutton to `<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">` in a browser overlay for a Firefox extension which I'd like to be displayed by default when the extension is first installed.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page provides an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Toolbar).